# Why do I get an "Aw Snap" while trying to open the settings page in Chrome and while trying to open some websites

Tags: browser

I keep getting the "Aw snap error" page in google chrome while trying to open the Chrome Settings page or while trying to open several websites. I have done my own research couldn't find an answer to this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the "Aw Snap" but a common cause is lack of memory, especially if it happens on built-in Chrome pages such as the settings page.

There's an "Aw Snap" troubleshooting guide [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) which I'd try first.

Comment: My installed RAM is 4GB. Should I upgrade it to 8GB RAM . I am not doing coding in this laptop and I dont have too many softwares in this laptop.

Comment: I couldn't advise on this, but I'd definitely check your resource usage and make sure you don't have a lot of things running in the background. I would also limit the amount of tabs you have open in Chrome at any one given moment, as each tab uses a separate process, which consumes CPU & Memory.

Comment: The guide I've linked to should give you all the information you need RE the "Aw Snap" page.

Comment: On the "Aw Snap" page there is also an error code. If you can provide such code the community may be able to provide further help or guidance.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as an answer if it helped or provide more information if you require further assistance.